# Error when trying to post MVC form with Dropdown list in it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I looked at similar posts but nothing working for my case.
I have a form which loads fine and I see the categories dropdown with all categories in it.
The problem is when I try to post the form.

I get this error:

*The ViewData item that has the key 'Category' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.*

*@Html.DropDownList("Category", Model.Categories) <-- red color*

Here is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Album", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmNewAlbum" }))
{                
   @Html.DropDownList("Category", Model.Categories)
}
```

Here is my model:

```
public class AlbumModel
{        
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Category { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; } <-- holds categories
}
```

This is the controller actions to view the page:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Save()
        {
            var model = new AlbumModel();
            var categories = new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Text = "-- pick --" } };
            categories.AddRange(svc.GetAll().Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Name }));
            model.Categories = categories;
            return View(model);
        }
```

Action that receives the post:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(AlbumModel model)
    {            
                var album = new AlbumDoc()
                {                        
                    Category = model.Category,
                    Title = model.Title,
                };

                svc.SaveAlbum(album);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your POST action you seem to be redisplaying the same view but you are not populating the `Categories` property on your view model which will contain the dropdown list values. And by the way I would recommend you using strongly typed helper. So:

```
public class AlbumController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Save()
    {
        var model = new AlbumModel();
        model.Categories = GetCategories();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(AlbumModel model)
    {            
        var album = new AlbumDoc()
        {                        
            Category = model.Category,
            Title = model.Title,
        };
        svc.SaveAlbum(album);
        model.Categories = GetCategories();
        return View(model);
    }

    private IList<SelectListItem> GetCategories()
    {
        return svc
            .GetAll()
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem
            { 
                Text = x.Name, 
                Value = x.Name 
            });
    }
}
```

and in your view:

```
@model AlbumModel
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Album", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmNewAlbum" }))
{                
   @Html.DropDownListFor(
       x => x.Category, 
       Model.Categories,
       -- pick --
   )
}
```

Comment: First one doesn't work, it says: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items. The second one also giving the old error.

Comment: Darrin, This is supposed to be an ajax post not full post. Why is it refreshing the page after clicking submit?

Comment: @Projapati - because you're not using Ajax.BeginForm?

Comment: @Projapati, I have updated my post a couple of times. Do you notice how I am setting the model.Categories property in both the GET and POST actions? As far as your second question about the AJAX post is concerned, I don't know how you are performing this AJAX post. Maybe you wrote some javascript or something? Maybe you wanted to use Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm? I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve here. But the error you described in your question is definitely due to the fact that in your POST action you didn't reinitialize the Categories property.

Comment: I got your point. Adding few extra lines to populate the categories made it work. Thanks